# How to remove an outdated malware entry in Windows security center

Tags: windows-10, security

In Windwos Security, a former download file still shows up, even though I deleted it a long time ago. I guess Windows Security just got confused when I deleted the file myself instead of using the official procedure/action.

So, how can I get rid of this unnecessary entry? I tried Windows support, they just re-installed Windows system files which changed (as expected) absolutely nothing.

[image]